# Installing Microsoft office 2010 across multiple drives

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, keyboard, ssd, microsoft-office

I've bought an ASUS TX300CA Windows 8 transformer tablet which has a detachable keyboard dock.

The tablet has a neat feature that although the detachable tablet part has only a 128Gb SSD, when you attach the keyboard dock, you get additional 500Gb of magnetic hard drive.

I want to install Microsoft Office 2010 so that some Office applications install on the tablet drive and some (such as Access, Visio, Project etc) - that would usually require keyboard work - to install on the dock drive.

There doesn't seem to be a mechanism to change the installation folder for the software.

Can it be done?

TIA,
Paolo

Comment: You will be unable to install Office in this way.  If you have purchased Office 2010 the install will install all of the applications depending on the version of Office 2010 you have in the same location.  While you can move the data yourself its unlikely to work.

Comment: No, it's not!  One is about complete applications. This is about splitting a single application.  The hardware information is about background to make sure paople aanswer the right question and not another...

Comment: @PaoloFCantoni these are effectively the same question as currently written. I would suggest [edit]ing this question to just ask if there's a way to install some Office applications to different locations.